# Localstorage - INSERT INTO DEMO VALUES WHERE id =

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql-server, cordova

I am working with Phonegap and Localstorage. I know how to insert new rows as well as deleting using an id. But, I can not figure out the syntax for inserting an item in an existing row, using the id. This is what I use, and it does not work, how shall I put it instead?

```
var sql = ('INSERT INTO DEMO (image) VALUES (?) WHERE id = ?', [id]); 
tx.executeSql(sql, [newImage], sucessQueryDB, errorCB);  //Does not work!!
```

When I delete I use:

```
var sql = 'DELETE FROM DEMO WHERE id=?';  
tx.executeSql(sql, [id], sucessQueryDB, errorCB); //Works fine!
```

I have also tried:
tx.executeSql(sql, [id, newImage], sucessQueryDB, errorCB);

Hope to get some good advice soon... / Malin

Comment: I think you're looking for [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I can not figure out the syntax for inserting an item in an existing row, using the id

You need to use the `Update` command and not the `Insert` command.

Like

```
Update DEMO 
Set image = 'somevalue'
where id = yourId
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have now tried:
var sql = 'UPDATE DEMO SET image = newImage WHERE id = id'; 
trans.executeSql(sql, sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
This does not work, is the syntax different in localstorage, than in ordinary SQL?

Comment: I think I have got it:
    var sql = 'UPDATE DEMO SET image = ? WHERE id=?'; 
    tx.executeSql(sql, [newImage, id], sucessQueryDB, errorCB);
Thanks again for helping me out.